# Rails + Nginx + Certbot: 422 Errors on Logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

I have a Rails 6 website running on Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2). I successfully implemented a process to use Certbot to generate an SSL certificate, and when I visit my website everything is working correctly. However, when I try to log in to my user console (using Devise), I receive 422 errors.

Rails Production Log

```
W, [2021-11-26T17:55:17.528942 #22645]  WARN -- : [6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] HTTP Origin header (https://example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://example.com)
I, [2021-11-26T17:55:17.529316 #22645]  INFO -- : [6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 565)
F, [2021-11-26T17:55:17.530195 #22645] FATAL -- : [6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6]
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6]
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:211:in `handle_unverified_request'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:243:in `handle_unverified_request'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] devise (4.8.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:238:in `verify_authenticity_token'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `block in invoke_before'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `each'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `invoke_before'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `block in run_callbacks'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actiontext (6.1.4.1) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actiontext (6.1.4.1) lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activerecord (6.1.4.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/server.rb:447:in `process_client'
[6ef6bfd6-6d78-4ded-90df-a9472e0d40f6] puma (5.5.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Puma Log (most recent lines, nothing relevant in here as far as I can tell)

```
[22565] - Worker 0 (PID: 22643) booted in 5.67s, phase: 0
[22565] - Worker 1 (PID: 22645) booted in 5.68s, phase: 0
```

Nginx Access Log

```
99.83.42.176 - - [26/Nov/2021:17:55:10 +0000] "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 200 7754 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36" "-"
99.83.42.176 - - [26/Nov/2021:17:55:17 +0000] "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 422 0 "https://example.com/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Nginx Error Log

```
2021/11/26 17:54:57 [notice] 22658#22658: signal process started
2021/11/26 17:54:57 [warn] 22626#22626: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2021/11/26 17:54:57 [warn] 22626#22626: conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

I've messed with a few options in nginx.conf but still haven't been able to track down why this is happening. This is my nginx.conf file, with the certbot-embedded changes:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65874;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    upstream appserver {
        server unix:/var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  on;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

        server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _; # managed by Certbot

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location appserver {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_pass http://appserver;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        }

    }

    server {

        if ($host = www.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        listen        80 ;
        server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced this problem, and know how to make sure nginx handles everything as https?

Not sure if this in related, but in the production config I have:

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

If I switch it to 'true', nothing loads at all. Not sure why, shouldn't that be 'true'?

Comment: I've started making a stab at answering your question but there are too many issues that need sorting out, you have no ip address or domain set so how did you get certbot to verify that you own the domain you are asking for certificates for? This is important because you your config will never work without the correct domains listed in your server block

Comment: I am using Route 53, which routes requests from the domain to the URL provided by Elastic Beanstalk. Certbot is able to call that URL, get an answer that I own the domain, and generate the correct certificate. When I visit example.com, my site is successfully serving the valid certificate.

Comment: OK, I am not as familiar with Amazon Web Services as I'd like to be

Comment: So it doesn't look like nginx is setting the proxy header, can you show the proxy settings and puma settings you have please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jamesc's suggestion ultimately led me to a solution. Elastic Beanstalk's AL2 Nginx confix file includes a webapp.conf file with the following block:

```
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

That wasn't passing through the full set of headers, and was resulting in invalid requests. I updated my nginx.conf file to provide an updated location block based on this thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22965.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass        http://my_app;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

Comment: I setup my nginx config file through capistrano3-puma, which assumed no SSL. (I don't know if that was a flag I might have missed.) Adding the -Proto, -Ssl, and -Port lines fixed my config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use ssl then using certbot is an ok solution to use but you should no longer serve http requests so you need to set your server block that listens on port 80 to redirect to an ssl block i.e. a block that listens on port 443.
This doesn't look like it is setup to act as a reverse proxy to your rails server either, there should be puma or unicorn or whatever rails server you are running declarations. so none of this really makes sense.

You have a few options set in your config that I am unfamiliar with plus you seem to have the sites_available options mixed in with the nginx.conf file, this is ok but it is not a normal nor very configurable setup, however, because of the few options you have that I am not familiar with I'm not going to comment on your options, I'm just going to make a suggestion that you tidy up your server blocks so that the block listening on port 80 redirects to the port 443 block. You will need to open up your firewall to allow port 443. If using ufw then there is an nginx app you can set otherwise I'll leave you to figure out or ask in a different question how to setup your specific firewall for SSL on port 443.

Anyway, besides the above you should change your port 80 http block to look like this

```
server {
  #no longer default server, all port 80, http requests, should be redirected to https port 443
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _;
    # really should be your production server name i.e. an.ip.address a_proper_domain.com a_proper_domain.co.uk www.a_proper_domain.com www.a_proper_domain.co.uk #provide a list of domains you are listening for separated by spaces
    #redirect to the https server block straight away, you do not want to have a site serving mixed https and http content it is a massive potential security hole
    return 301 https://$host$1$request_uri;
}
```

So that your config looks like this

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65874;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

server {
  #no longer default server, all port 80, http requests, should be redirected to https port 443
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _;
    # really should be your production server name i.e. an.ip.address a_proper_domain.com a_proper_domain.co.uk www.a_proper_domain.com www.a_proper_domain.co.uk #provide a list of domains you are listening for separated by spaces
    return 301 https://$host$1$request_uri;
}

    server {
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

    server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}

    server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen        80 ;
    server_name www.example.com example.com localhost _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}}
```

Usually your capistrano deployment scripts will take care of setting up the nginx config for you if using capistrano 3 gem with capistrano3 puma gem if you are using puma as your rails server, there are also capistrano nginx gems as well but if using puma in production then I highly recommend using the correct configuration with your nginx.config file including the sites_enabled folder and setting up your specific server requirements in a separate file that lives in the appropriate location e.g. /etc/nginx/sites_available folder and gets symlinked to the sites_available folder. This is the standard approach that most server admins or dev ops would expect the setup to look like.

In your SSL server block you should have settings for your puma server and a typical setup is something like this

```
  location @name_of_your_puma_socket {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # this is your issue I think
    proxy_pass http://name_of_your_puma_socket;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log #set the path to your nginx.access log
    error_log # set the path to your nginx.error.log;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using Puma, if that is helpful context. This is also the default nginx.conf file generated by Elastic Beanstalk (Ruby) on Amazon Linux 2 (save for the Certbot portion). I'll look into overriding some of the values you suggested (I was suspecting that the default listens on port 80 looked odd), though I would be surprised if I need to deviate from the auto-generated configuration that is already working save for the 422 issue.

Comment: @Chakron, you are welcome, I'd recommend gzip being on, I can not see where nginx is setting up the location of the puma socket but maybe that is declared in the included `conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;` files so I'll not comment further

Comment: Unfortunately, making the changes you suggested in the server block made no difference. There must be something else going on here.

Yes, should be taking place in the conf files. Set up at /var/run/puma/my_app.sock

Comment: @Chakron You need to look in your nginx error log and your puma error and access logs plus your rails production log to track down the issue, update your question with this info and I'll see if I can help further

Comment: Added the full stack trace from the Rails production log, the nginx access and error logs, and the Puma log.

Comment: @Chakron, see my updated answer, hope it helps

Comment: No luck so far - I've updated my post to show my current nginx.conf. At the top of the http block I added "upstream appserver" so I can refer to the puma socket by name, then I added the location block you mentioned to the SSL server block. Notice anything incorrect?

Comment: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` shows that the error is due to CSRF token, isn't it? Did you check the token in the form matched with the csrf-token in the head?

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="...">`
`<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="...">`

Comment: @kevinluo201, yes, you are correct and this CSRF token error is because of the first line in the rails production log stating the following `HTTP Origin header (https://example.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://example.com)` showing that the nginx configuration is not passing the correct header onto puma and also possibly because the domain names are not correctly set up, but that may just be a red herring in this case as the requests are coming in to the server via AWS `Route53`

Comment: This is in a subfolder below nginx.conf and gets copied over during deployment, explains some of how this was working in the first place at least: https://gist.github.com/chsh/38711a075511879d863b. Working on updating that location block now.